# MessageDialog closes Popup

Tags: windows-8, popup, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, messagedialog

in my **Popup** windows (contains game options control) I have "Reset HighScores" Button. Button fire a **MessageDialog** with a TextBlock "Are you sure that ..." and two Buttons "Yes" and "No". However, when MessageDialog opens, Popup closes. Do you know how to make popup still alive?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get around this using an `Action` delegate as a callback for when the `MessageDialog` is closed.

The key is to call the Action after an `await` on `MessageDialog`'s `ShowAsync` in an `async` function.

Another key is to Close and Open your popup to get the `IsLightDismissEnabled` to actually take hold.

XAML:

```xml
<Popup
    IsLightDismissEnabled="{Binding IsLightDismiss, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

ViewModel:

```csharp
private bool isPopupOpen;
public bool IsPopupOpen
{
    get { return this.isPopupOpen; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this.isPopupOpen, value); }
}

private bool isLightDismiss;
public bool IsLightDismiss
{
    get { return this.isLightDismiss; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this.isLightDismiss, value); }
}

protected void ShowDialog()
{
    this.IsLightDismiss = false;
    this.IsPopupOpen = false;
    this.IsPopupOpen = true;
    Action showPopup = () => {
        this.IsLightDismiss = true;
        this.IsPopupOpen = false;
        this.IsPopupOpen = true;
    };
    ShowMessageDialog("message", "title", showPopup);
}
```

```csharp
private async void ShowMessageDialog(string message, string title, Action callback)
{
    var _messageDialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);
    await _messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set your `Popup`'s `IsLightDismissEnabled` property to `false` to achieve that.

```
popup.IsLightDismissEnabled = false;
```

Comment: you should add `popup.LostFocus` event handler then, in event handler you can make sure it stays open