# MessageDialog closes PopUp with IsLightDismissEnabled=True

Tags: vb.net, popup, windows-runtime, messagedialog

I have a PopUp to simulate a FlyOut. Its property `IsLightDismissEnabled` is set to `True`.
When I display a MessageDialog from within the PopUp, the focus change automatically closes the PopUp. I don't want this to happen.
It works correctly if I set `IsLightDismissEnabled` to `False`, however this is not how it's supposed to work, since I want the PopUp to disappear when the focus is lost, but not when a message is shown.

Is there a way to achieve such a functionality?

Comment: A very similar question has been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323752/messagedialog-closes-popup/

Comment: This worked, thanks!
However, I needed to change my PopUp from a dynamically generated one to a globally available, otherwise this will not work since you lose the PopUp when you set isOpen to false.